# How can I correctly measure the runtime of a program in Linux?

Tags: linux, runtime, exe

I need to measure the runtime of an executable file in Linux.
Because I do not have the source code, I can not make it print out the runtime automatically.

I also tried to use the "time" commend, but the problem is that this program requires the users to choose different operation modes by pressing some buttons on the keyboard.  Therefore, this "using thinking and pressing button" delay will also be involved.

Could anybody tell me how to measure the runtime of this program?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you pipe a fixed set of input to the program?  Something like:
`time prog < input.txt`

Comment: Hi, is this question about how I run this program?   This program needs to read 2 input files and then generate 1 output file ( the commend i used here is:  program -f input1.txt -b  input2.txt -p output.txt  ). I am a beginner so I am not quite familiar with "pipe", could you please give me some instructions?

Comment: The basic idea is that you can put what someone would normally type into a file, and then tell the program to read it's input from that file instead of the keyboard like it normally does..
Here's a brief tutorial: http://www.le.ac.uk/oerresources/bdra/unix/page_56.htm